# How to create a new environment which 'after' argument starts with "}"?

Tags: environments, brackets

**Context:** I want to create a custom environment. For that, I use the command `\newenvironment{<environment-name>}{<before>}{<after>}`. However, in my case, `<after>` starts with `}`, so LaTeX thinks this bracket closes the definition of `<after>`...

**Question:** How to create a new environment where `<after>` starts with `}`?

---

**MWE:** In the example below, I define an environment that creates a `tikzpicture` and a `node` around the content thereof.
(I know an easy workaround would be to use `newcommand` instead, but my real case requires an environment.)

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \newenvironment{myenvironment}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[draw, red]{
    }{%
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{myenvironment}
        Foo bar
    \end{myenvironment}
\end{document}
```

---

**Tested non-working solutions:**

- I have tried `\newenvironment{<environment-name>}{<before>}{\null<after>}` but it doesn't work.
- I have also tried to change `{` and `}` by `\bgroup` and `\egroup` repectively - both for the environment definition (`\newenvironment{<environment-name>} \bgoup <before>\egroup\bgroup <after>\egroup`), or in the `node` definition (`... \node[draw, red]\bgroup}{\egroup; ...`). No success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `environ`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myenvironment}{%
  \tikz{\node[draw, red]{\BODY};}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{myenvironment}
  Foo bar
\end{myenvironment}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The braces around the argument of `\node` are true “argument-delimiters”, aren’t they?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Er .... Why?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I just know this is how, say, the `forest` environment is defined and, indeed, how `prooftree` is defined. I figured it would work here, too. (I don't mean I didn't test it - I did test it and it did work.)

Comment: Oh, it *will* work, that’s certain.  But, as you probably know, this approach is highly inefficient from TeX’s point of view.  So, I was wondering whether `\node` absorbs its `{...}` argument wholly before processing it (as I would expect), or it processes it in the same way as, say, `\hbox{...}` processes its “argument”.  But the second case is actually ruled out, for otherwise `\newenvironment{myenvironment}{... \node[...] \bgroup}{\egroup ...}` would have worked.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I didn't know it was inefficient. Can't say I had thought about it. Certainly I've thought about `prooftrees` being slow, but that is mostly due to `forest` and `pgf` being slow. I just knew it was *safe* - or thought I did, until I wondered if you were suggesting not.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I have no idea what `\hbox{}` does either.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Actually, I do know it is inefficient, but I wouldn't know it was highly or moderately so. That is, as I understand it, it is less efficient when TeX has to parse through a whole bunch of stuff before doing anything with it, as opposed to processing it as it goes along. However, I have no idea why I think this, so it is probably wrong.

Comment: No, please, don’t take my remark that seriously! :-)  After all, there absolutely no point in worrying about the (supposed) inefficiency of `environ` when you are using TikZ!  It’s just that, having witnessed the legendary days when the numbers of the typeset pages `[1] [2] [3] [4]…` formed a sort of worm slowly working its way across the terminal emulator of my 68k-powered macintosh, I cannot dismiss the habit of being concerned about this kind of things…

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti For what it is worth various Forest features got added in order to let me rewrite `prooftrees` with minimal use of `pgfmath` because it really can be very slow indeed, even on an i3 and even by Ti*k*Z standards - even, indeed, by Forest standards. (I know that's not the newest thing or anything like, but it is much more than TeX could originally have dreamed of.)